# Why am I suddenly getting a segmentation fault for LMMS?

Tags: linux-mint, segmentation-fault

Just like the title, with LMMS both from the OS repo and built from Github. I've gotten no error reports during compilation, with full repos for Carla and VSTs. Still, the terminal reports:

```
michael@Selkie:~/opt/lmms/build$ ./lmms
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Notice: could not set realtime priority.
qt5ct: palette support is disabled
qt5ct: custom style sheet is disabled
VST sync support disabled in your configuration
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Same behavior for the stock LMMS.

```
michael@Selkie:~/opt/lmms/build$ lmms
Notice: could not set realtime priority.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea why it's doing this. Has anyone else had a similar issue? I know I've used it on this machine in the past.

My OS is Linux Mint 19.1, using Maté DE. Wine is version 3.6; I know LMMS had issues with that about ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Apparently I had a corrupt (and don't worry, home-rolled) LADSPA library that was causing LMMS to choke on startup. I discovered this by running gdb and looking at the bug source a little closer. I removed it, and the problem has been resolved.

Funny, I would have expected Audacity to have a similar issue, and it works fine.